# vbscript click on button/image

Tags: vbscript

I am creating a vbscript to automatically fill in a webpage. However, I am unable to figure out click on the final submit but as there is no id or tag.

```
<A onclick="submitForm('DefaultFormName',1,
{'wklEvent':'RR0','serverValidate':'1',event:'respond'});return false;" 
href="#"><IMG border=0 alt=Approve 
src="/OA_HTML/cabo/images/cache/en/bApprMsEb-6.gif" width=63 align=absMiddle 
height=18></A>
```

Edit: I was able to get it working using the code below

Dim ele As Object

```
        For Each ele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
         If InStr(ele.innerHTML, "bAdd_-X_1-7.gif") > 0 Then
              ele.FireEvent ("onclick")
          End If

        Next ele
```

Comment: are you sure vbscript is executed ? if you didn't change the default local scripting engine javascript will be used

Comment: Yes, this is the last step of the program and all of the other steps are executing. I was able to navigate the other windows by calling the button name or ID.

Comment: in chrome or firefox display the console (F12), use the top left iocn "select an element on the page to inspect" and select the element you need, in the elements tab rightclick the element and select "copy/copy selector". paste the path somewhere, try the console to get to the element in the DOM using this path, it should be possible to do this with vbscript but using javascript would be easier